# Simplifying a certain SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate a delta of contents of two tables - `@i` and `@j`:

```
DECLARE @i TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Modified] [int] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @j TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Exported] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

The delta should contain just one column - `Id` and be calculated like this:

1. Any `Id` in the result is coming from `@i` or `@j` or both (i.e. `FULL JOIN`)
2. If `@i.Id` is not found in `@j` or found, but `@j.Code = 'D'`, then `@i.Id` is taken.
3. If `@i.Id` is found in `@j` and `@j.Exported < @i.Modified`, then `@i.Id` is taken.
4. If `@j.Code <> 'D'` and `@j.Id` is not found in `@i`, then `@j.Id` is taken.

Here is the SQL I came with:

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.Id, j.Id) Id
FROM @i i
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM @j WHERE Code <> 'D') j ON i.Id = j.Id
WHERE j.Exported IS NULL OR i.Modified IS NULL OR (j.Exported < i.Modified)
```

And this [SQL works great](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35380).

For example:

```
INSERT INTO @i VALUES (1,0),(2,0)
INSERT INTO @j VALUES (1,'D',1),(2,'C',1)
```

The delta is `1`.

My question is this - can I simplify this SQL query by eliminating the nested select statement?

I tried this one:

```
SELECT COALESCE(i.Id, j.Id) Id
FROM @i i
FULL JOIN @j j ON Code <> 'D' AND i.Id = j.Id
WHERE j.Exported IS NULL OR i.Modified IS NULL OR (j.Exported < i.Modified)
```

But it produces two rows - `1` and `1`. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35381).

**EDIT**

Guys, I am intentionally giving a very simple example still demonstrating the problem. In reality the queries are more complex, the keys are actually composite keys and the result of the delta is not a simple `Id`, but a bit more. But the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding that a case statement is inappropriate for your application, I can suggest this:

```
-- 1. Any Id in the result is coming from @i or @j or both (i.e. FULL JOIN)
-- 2. If @i.Id is not found in @j or found, but @j.Code = 'D', then @i.Id is taken.
-- 3. If @i.Id is found in @j and @j.Exported < @i.Modified, then @i.Id is taken.
-- 4. If @j.Code <> 'D' and @j.Id is not found in @i, then @j.Id is taken

SELECT COALESCE(i.Id, j.Id) Id
FROM @i AS i
FULL JOIN @j AS j ON i.Id = j.Id
WHERE 
  (i.Id IS NOT NULL AND
  ( -- #2
    j.Id IS NULL OR j.Code = 'D' OR
    -- #3
   (j.Exported IS NOT NULL AND j.Exported < i.Modified))
  )
  -- #4
  OR (i.Id IS NULL AND j.Code <> 'D');
```

Comment: Yep, turns out pretty simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to evaluate these conditions using a case statement. Im not certain I got all of your edge cases covered, but here is your logic quickly converted into a case:

```
DECLARE @i TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Modified] [int] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @j TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Exported] [int] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @i values (1,0)
insert into @i values (2,0)
INSERT INTO @j VALUES (1,'D',1)
insert into @j values (2,'C',1)

--The delta should contain just one column - Id and be calculated like this:

--Any Id in the result is coming from @i or @j or both (i.e. FULL JOIN)
--If @i.Id is not found in @j or found, but @j.Code = 'D', then @i.Id is taken.
--If @i.Id is found in @j and @j.Exported < @i.Modified, then @i.Id is taken.
--If @j.Code <> 'D' and @j.Id is not found in @i, then @j.Id is taken.



select  [Id] =  max(case 
                    when j.Code = 'D' then i.Id
                    when j.Id is not null and j.Exported < i.Modified then i.Id
                    when j.Code <> 'D' and i.Id is null then j.Id
                    else -1 -- ??
                end)

from    @i i 
left
join    @j j on i.Id = j.Id
```

Comment: This is not something I can use in a real application.